# SQL - sum of some rows, minus sum of other rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in mySQL with the following columns:

```
CUSTOMER_CODE | TRANS_TYPE | TRANS_VALUE
```

TRANS_TYPE could be either "DRINV" (a sale) or "DRCDT" (a credit).

I want to get the total sales per customer, so my query so far is:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_CODE, SUM(TRANS_VALUE) as SALES FROM DR_TRANS GROUP BY CUSTOMER_CODE
```

Problem is this is totaling the sales *and* credits, instead of giving be sales minus credits. I want the results to be

```
SUM(TRANS_VALUE) where TRANS_TYPE = "DRINV" - SUM(TRANS_VALUE) where TRANS_TYPE = "DRCDT".
```

Is it possible to do this in a SQL query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select customer_code,
       sum(case
             when trans_type = 'DRINV' then
              trans_value
             else
              -trans_value
           end) as net_sales
  from dr_trans
 group by customer_code
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Use CASE caluse:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_CODE,
SUM(CASE WHEN TRANS_TYPE = 'DRINV' THEN TRANS_VALUE ELSE (- TRANS_VALUE) END ) as SALES
FROM DR_TRANS GROUP BY CUSTOMER_CODE
```